# I am getting an Atribute error that the object image does not have atibute open when I import using PIL

Tags: python

I want to rotate an image but I can't even open it. The answer I found does not work for me. I tried doing import PIL.Image but that doesn't work either. Any answers would be very helpful

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
from math import *
from random import * 
from PIL import *



imageCar = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Antonio\\Desktop\\Python Programs\\GameFinal\\car.png")
```

Comment: Post the full traceback error message you are getting

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open' This is the trace bar error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's considered [bad practice to use `*` when importing from a package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386740/6271889), exactly because it just dumps everything from that package into your code. If two different packages have something with the same name (like in your code `tkinter.Image` and `PIL.Image`), you get some strange errors.

It's unfortunate that [the documentation for tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) uses `from tkinter import *` as an example.

What you want is to selectively import what you need:

```py
# Only import what you need. When imported like this, you
# use its name directly
from tkinter import TK
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
```

If I'm calling an imported function just a couple time throughout my code, I usually import it like so as to not pollute my namespace:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

# Prefix it with the package name you used to import
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

A pretty good tutorial on importing is

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-modules-in-python-3